# Unable to assign fs.readFile data to factory object property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am attempting to make a call to fs.readFile within an Angularjs service which is an object containing both methods and properties.

I call fs.readFile from within a method of the service object, and attempt to assign the data read to a property of the service object, but this always results in undefined. The below code should make my intentions clear;

```
    angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).controller('exampleCtrl', function(objectFac){
        objectFac.func();
        console.log(objectFac.prop); // Undefined
        console.log(objectFac.object.prop); // Undefined
    });

   angular.module('myApp.Services').service('objectFac', function (){
        this.prop = '';
        this.object.prop = '';
        this.func = function(){
            this.param = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8'); //If I use a call back (non Sync) and log the data to console, it shows correctly but I cannot assign it to objectFac.prop or object.prop. 
    };
```

I have tried both readFile and readFileSync, the same occurs with both. I am able to log the data retrieved from the file to console, just not assign to the object property I want. It always results in undefined.

Thanks.

Comment: I understand you use node-webkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

services are created using the `new` keword in angular so in order to fix your issue, this:

```js
angular.module('myApp.Services').service('objectFac', function() {
          this.prop = '';
          this.object.prop = '';
          this.func = function() {
            this.param = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8');
}
```

becomes:

```js
angular.module('myApp.Services').service('objectFac', function() {
      return function() {
          this.prop = '';
          this.object.prop = '';
          this.func = function() {
            this.param = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8');
          }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Muli. I did wonder about this towards the beginning of the project but hadn't run into any issues so assumed I had done it correctly. Another question if you wouldn't mind; will this return the same object from inside each controller, or by returning a new function on each call am I in effect creating a separate object each time? I use the service to keep track of key information / state across several controllers. Thanks :)

Comment: Angular uses singleton pattern for services which means it'll be generated once across all the app. check out the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: Also if this answer helped you, please accept it :)

Comment: Great, thanks Muli. Also... :)... After making your suggested changes, the other calls to the Service object's methods are now failing from within the controller. E.G from within a controller that uses the service as a dependency;

objectFac.updateSomeDataWithinObject();

This is now returning undefined. I have printed the new object to console and I can confirm it has the method, and it is being instantiated when the service is called. Scope in angular is blowing my mind :D

Comment: As an addition; I am calling the service objects method; from inside a function within the $scope for that controller:

mycontroller.. function($scope, objectFac){
    $scope.someFunc = function(){
       objectFac.updateSomeDatawithinObject();
  }
}

// updateSomeDataWithinObject is undefined

Comment: It's difficult to understand without the error from the console, can you attach it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99131/discussion-between-rayd44-and-muli-yulzary).